# "responsible of" vs "responsible for"

Tags: prepositions

What's more correct form?

> responsible **for**
>
> responsible **of**

For example:

> The Central nervous system is responsible **for** the receiving
>   signals from the Peripheral nervous system.
>
> The Central nervous system is responsible **of** the receiving signals
>   from the Peripheral nervous system.

Answer (score 15):

The usual usage is

> responsible **for** *something*
>   The night guard is responsible **for** turning off the lights.
>
> responsibility **of** *someone*
>   It is the responsibility **of** the night guard to turn off the lights.

Answer (score 4):

We generally use **responsible for**.

> The Central nervous system is **responsible for** the receiving signals from the Peripheral nervous system.

By the way, there's a little mistake in your example. Perhaps separate the **for** and the **the**:

> The Central nervous system is responsible **for** receiving **the** signals from the Peripheral nervous system.

Or remove the **the**:

> The Central nervous system is responsible for receiving signals from the Peripheral nervous system.